# PHP upload pics with space

Tags: php, image, upload

I have an upload pictures form. I need to make sure that pictures which contain spaces in the name are replaced with something else, my guess is `%`.

ie the picture's name is:  `aa 22.jpg`

If uploaded this way it does not show because of the space between `aa` and `22`.  What is the way to get rid of the space or replace it with `%` when uploaded?

Comment: You're probably talking about `%20` which is the URL encoded version of a space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

rather than replacing file name with empty string, it is good idea to replace it with an underscore to maintain the readability and actual name of the file in its sense:

`$file = str_replace(' ', '_', $file);`

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just...

```
$filename = str_replace(' ', '', $filename);
```

Are you using some upload handler that you don't have control over?

Comment: I am using an upload class which would be too tricky to change. I was thinking at something more directly involved with upload file.

Comment: So when you use the class, does it fail when you upload a file that contains a space?  If it fails, you'll need to fix the class itself... if it succeeds and returns you the filename with the space, simply use the rename() function to remove the spaces...

Answer (score 1):

you can use `trim($picture)`, but dont know where to put it, finding out my self right now

Answer (score 0):

If the file uploads correctly but just doesn't show up in the browser, you might try `aa%2022.jpg`, since %20 is used instead of spaces in URLs (and iirc some browser won't realize this automatically).

But since it's ugly, you might prefer replacing spaces with something else. You can use `str_replace` function to achieve this.